# Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets to 2 columns

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a conditional formatting that will update my status column.
If today's is greater than due date and is "Open", if today's date less than today and is "Open" another format.

I tried this: `=AND(E{current_row} TODAY(),F{current_row}="Open")`
I had a "less than" before TODAY.

Comment: I believe you are looking for a [multi-criteria formula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/100813). [WebApps SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) might be a more appropriate site for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please select ColumnF and delete any existing CF rules for it then Format - Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is** and:

```
=and(today()>$E1,$F1="Open")
```

with one formatting of your choice and then **Add another rule** of:

```
=and(today()<$E1,$F1="Open")
```

with another choice of formatting.

This does however leave entries dated today unformatted by either rule.